# Rounding problems with DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following queries:

```
DECLARE @__dateRange_StartDate_4 DATETIME ='2021-03-01T00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @__dateRange_EndDate_3 DATETIME ='2021-03-31T23:59:59.999'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000', '2021-03-31T23:59:59.999') + 1

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @__dateRange_StartDate_4, @__dateRange_EndDate_3) + 1

SELECT @__dateRange_EndDate_3
```

Produces the following results:

> 31

> 32

> 2021-04-01 00:00:00.000

It appears `@__dateRange_EndDate_3` is being rounded to the next day, which I don't want.

What is the correct way to have the second `SELECT` return 31?

*Note: My queries are actually being called from Entity Framework so I may be limited to what I can do here, but I at least want to understand the issue as this was unexpected.*

Comment: Try using datetime2. datetime is not accurate to 1/10000 second. In my experience datetime gets rounded to the nearest 3/10000

Comment: @JonathanWillcock `datetime` is accurate to 1/300 of a second, not 3/10000.

Comment: [Rounding of datetime Fractional Second Precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision) seems pretty clear on the topic. Since your assignment to `@__dateRange_EndDate_3` stores `2021-04-01T00:00:00.000` the answer is that the second `select` returns the correct result.

Comment: @HABO: The business need is for the first result.

Comment: @Larnu. Sorry apart from one 0 too many, what I was talking about is rounding. In my experience whatever milliseconds get entered, on being saved this will get altered by a maximum of 2 milliseconds up or down. (I believe this to be correct). I have a rather perverse way of looking at the world, and am even worse at expressing it :-)

Comment: good related article on datetimes: 
https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATETIME` in SQL Server has an accuracy of **3.33ms** (0.003 seconds) - therefore, the "highest" possible value for March 31, 2021 would be `2021-03-31T23:59:59.997` - anything beyond that will be rounded up to the next day.

This is just one of the reasons why as of SQL Server **2008** the general recommendation is to use `DATE` for when you don't need any time portion, or `DATETIME2(n)` (when you need the time portion; `n` is the number of fractional digits after the second - can be 0 through 7) datatypes.

`DATETIME2(n)` offers accuracy down to **100 ns** and thus   `2021-03-31T23:59:59.999`  will be absolutely no problem in a `DATETIME2(3)` column.

As an added benefit, `DATETIME2(n)` also doesn't have this "arbitrary" lower limits of supported dates only through 01.01.1753 - with `DATETIME2(n)` you can store any date, back to 1 AD

Comment: As I indicated in the question, I'm actually calling this via Entity Framework. So I have limited control over the query. But I can adjust my end date such that it won't be rounded to the next day.

Comment: @JonathanWood: you could use data annotations to make sure your tables use `DATETIME2(n)` instead of `DATETIME` for storing date & time values.

Answer (score 1):

This is silly.  Don't bother with trying to get the last increment before a time -- and learning that `datetime` is only accurate to 0.003 seconds.

Express the logic only using dates:

```
DECLARE @__dateRange_StartDate_4 DATE ='2021-03-01'
DECLARE @__dateRange_EndDate_3 DATE ='2021-04-01'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01');

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @__dateRange_StartDate_4, @__dateRange_EndDate_3);

SELECT @__dateRange_EndDate_3;
```

Then use these with inequalities:

```
WHERE date >= @__dateRange_StartDate_4 AND
      date < @__dateRange_EndDate_3
```

Inequalities -- with `>=` and `<` is the recommended way to handle date/time comparisons.  Dealing with the "last increment" problem is only one of the problems it solves.

If you *really* are committed to figuring out the last increment before midnight, you can use `DATETIME2` or `.997`.  But I don't recommend either of those approaches.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3475fc415dd9fc36224f12789937658b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Would you consider everything that doesn't take into consideration everything you know to be silly?

Comment: As far as comparing the values, I'm not sure how that helps me get the number of days spanned by the two `DATETIME`s. Are you showing me something there that I missed? I don't need to know which is greater. The name of these variables pretty much establishes that.

Comment: @JonathanWood . . . Basically, I want to point out that you should not be using `datetime` when you are trying to express a range of **dates**.  If you do use `datetimes` you should use valid `datetime` values.  See the last paragraph.  What is silly is using microsecond precision to express date ranges.  That is not meant in a cruel way, it just seems very overengineered.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think the correct term is "half-open interval", inequalities themselves don't necessarily help unless you close one side with `>=` or `<=` as you have done